# unable to install mongodb on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mongodb

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and am trying to install MongoDB.

Per http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ I do `sudo apt-get install mongodb-org` and this is the output I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
```

So how do I install mongodb? Is compiling from source my only option?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: @muru - see http://pastebin.com/WMvkpK3h . I can't get it installed on 15.04 either..

Comment: That doesn't list the MongoDB repositories. Did you add their repositories as given in steps 1 and 2?

Comment: to install on 15.04, see here: http://askubuntu.com/a/659216/167115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **ALL** the commands below, command by command

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

<sub>[Source](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This command worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
```

Comment: I'd love the delete-voters to justify their votes with comments. **This answer isn't inaccurate; it installs MongoDB**.  The caveat is it'll install version 2.4.9 (current is 3.4.6). 2.4 left upstream support back in 2016 so unless other people (its Ubuntu maintainer, or Debian) have been patching it, it's likely not the best option.